# Runtime of set! and begin in Scheme/Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Does anyone know what the runtime of `set!` and `begin` is in Scheme/Racket?

I think `set!` is constant but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

set! is O(1). 
There is no difference in this regard between Scheme and other languages.

Answer (score 2):

The `set!` operation simply associates ("binds") a value to a symbol, surely that's `O(1)` in any self-respecting programming language. Looking for a binding might not necessarily be `O(1)` depending on implementation details, but that's an entirely different matter (I don't know the specifics for Racket).

Regarding `begin`, that's a sequencing form, applying it doesn't have a cost per-se, only its contents (the expressions it holds inside) will determine its time complexity. Same thing for `set!`, the *value* part of the assignment might take some time to evaluate, but the `set!` operation itself is `O(1)`

Answer (score 2):

One caveat: set! and begin both have subexpressions. If either of these takes a long time, then evaluation of the set! (or begin) will, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about the performance of `set!`, keep in mind that avoiding mutation can be faster. See [Racket Guide: Mutation and Performance](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/performance.html#%28part._.Mutation_and_.Performance%29).